# Mostrar el mas bajo de los salarios, el más alto de los salarios,la suma de todos los salarios y el promedio de todos los salarios

Tags: sql

Hola tengo una duda con este ejercicio.

Escriba una consulta que muestre el mas bajo de los salarios, el más alto de los salarios, la suma de todos los salarios y el promedio de todos los salarios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es la duda?

Comment: hint: todas son funciones de agregación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que la tabla se llama EMPLEADO y el campo Salario:

```
SELECT MAX(Salario) AS MAX_SALARIO, MIN(Salario) AS MIN_SALARIO, SUM(Salario) AS SUMA_SALARIO, AVG(Salario) AS MEDIA_SALARIO FROM EMPLEADO
```

Comment: Gracias por hacerle la tarea.